# Finding and replacing strings in cells of a matrix in R

Tags: r, regex, relational-database

I'm trying to process a survey, in which one of the questions asks the respondents to name a friend. Now I have a matrix like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/pW5ZcTI.png]

I want to save these results in a relational database. I have assigned every person a unique ID, and want the answers to be saved as a last of ID's. So that the table looks like this:

[image]

My code so far:

i've tried

```
df$name %in% df$friends
```

which did not give any results. I'm now trying to use a for loop with str_detect:

```
friends <- df$friends
names <- df$name
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  friends_called <- str_detect(friends, names[i])
  id_index <- grep(names[i], df$name)
  id <- df$id[id_index]
  for (j in 1:length(friends_called)) {
    if(friends_called[j] == T) {
      df$friends_id[j] <- paste(df$friends_id[j], id, ",", sep="")
    }
df$friends <- df$friends_id
```

But I have some issues with it:

1. It's not working
2. It uses two loops, which i'm used to from writing python but I read that i should avoid them in R
3. The string matching needs to be fuzzy (If Anna wrote "Jon" instead of "John", it should still match.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a loop in `tidyverse` as follows:

```
df %>%
  mutate(friends = map(friends, ~ df %>% 
                         filter(str_detect(.x,name)) %>% 
                         select(id) %>% 
                         unlist() %>% 
                         paste(collapse = ',')))
```

gives

```
   id   name friends
1 a1d   John b2e,c3f
2 b2e   Anna     a1d
3 c3f Denise
```

or with base R you can use sapply:

```
df$friends <- sapply(friends, function(x) paste(id[str_detect(x,name)],collapse = ','))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've used the code with base R, since i'm still pretty new and i'd like to dive more into tinyverse when my understanding is better.

Comment: just start with `tidyverse` and combine it with what you already know of base R. In the end `tidyverse` is easier to understand and work with (at least for me).